# Is there a function for the revit API (visual studio c#) that provides me with information on which button was clicked by a user?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, onclick, revit-api

I'm working on a recent button on my ribbon panel that displays the button that was last clicked but I don't know how to obtain information on what button was clicked from that same ribbon panel.

Comment: Please present a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is your own ribbon panel and you have complete control over it, the easiest solution that comes to mind would be for you to keep track of the last button clicked yourself.